# Spring Security + Auth LDAP : BindRequest and UnbindRequest?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

After days of Google researching, Reading The F* Spring Security Manual and testing, I'm becoming desperate ...

The context : I'm implementing a Micro-Services architecture with Eureka etc...
I implemented an Auth Service which works very well with a MySQL authentication database. But now, I want to join my company LDAP through an OpenLDAP who works adequately.

So, I'm trying to join the LDAP with my spring security authentication.

The code of my configure() method (I replaced my company and domain name, the account {0} is "test"):

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://myldap/ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=mycompany")
    .and()
        .userDnPatterns("cn={0}");
```

I also tried different ways to write this and all the time, I get Bad Credentials or LDAP 32 error. With userDnPattern, usersearchbase method, passwordcompare, passwordencoder and others. I also tried to put DC in the root() method and the OU in the group...() method, no change (I think in fact that Spring Security sort these parameters smartly before sending LDAP Requests). To be honest, I tried 357654 differents ways to write the configure() method ...

The problem is that : When I put the same config, credentials, domains ... in an LDAP explorer software, **it works correctly**.

So I monitored LDAP networks exchanges with Wireshark and I saw this :
[Wireshark screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqfvq.png)

As we can see, there's 8 requests exchanged. The first 5 are OK. It find my account "test" correctly. But there's three over requests (with the unbindRequest which going back).

The problem is that Spring give me the result of the last request and say me the account doesn't exist or the credentials don't work, etc...

Have you got a clue for this ? Do you know how Spring Security works to question LDAP ? How can I do to contact my LDAP adequately with the framework ?

Thank you for reading.

*Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem and got a solution.

My enterprise LDAP is an LDAP above an AD.

And this LDAP+AD needs Bind Authentication and doesn't authorize anonymous bind then authentication.

In Spring Security, there's an object which can do this : **BindAuthenticator**

This is how I try to use it (and it works).

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
      authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
 }

 @Bean
 public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
      LdapAuthenticationProvider lAP = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticator(), ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
      return lAP;
 }

 @Bean
 public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() throws Exception {
      DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource([URL of the LDAP]);

      return contextSource;
 }

 @Bean
 public LdapAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator() throws Exception {
      BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(ldapContextSource());
      authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] {"CN={0},"+[MY ENTERPRISE LDAP FILTER]});          
      return authenticator;
 }
```

Hope this sample code will help some people ...

Thank you !